# Does it take more force to travel up the stairs or to travel up the slope next to it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, estimation, biology

The answer might depend on numerous factors (steepness of steps, steepness of stairs etc.) Consider the length of the stairs and slope equal.

Comment: If there is no friction, the slope is unclimbable, the stairs are not (in principle), so friction is also important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping all the biological and anatomical factors aside, I do have a proposal.

For Climbing the step you are required to use $F_{stair}>mg$ but climbing the slope you would only require $F_{slope}>mg-Ncos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle of inclination of the slope and N is the Normal force acting upward.

So clearly climbing a slope seems to take lesser force than climbing the stairs as $min(F_{slope})<min(F_{stairs})$.